# Will it hurt my chances if I separate the research and teaching experience in my full academic CV?

Tags: job-search, europe, assistant-professor, netherlands

I'm applying for an assistant professor position to a certain university/institute in Netherlands, and I'm thinking of separating my research (academic/industrial) and teaching (academic) experiences in my CV, because of the following reasons:

1. I've taught for over 1200 hours in EU and the US, and I want to reserve a section in my CV highlighting that in great detail, thinking that it might make a positive impression if I detail my teaching experience by specifying subjects, teaching methods and number of hours etc.
2. The teaching (currently I've a teaching only position in a university in EU and I also taught during my PhD) is/has been done separately from the research in academia and industry, at different times.*

But I'm wondering if it'll hurt my chances because

1. The selection committee may not get a clear chronological idea of my work experience (although a 5 minute scrutiny would easily tell them that).
2. It's perhaps not in the usual practice.

So I'm weighing the pros vs cons here. Do you think it'll hurt my chances if I separate the research and teaching experience in my CV as separate work experience as "Work experience (research)" and "Work experience (teaching)"?

Comment: Why not just sections "Research" and "Teaching"?

Comment: @Buffy That's a good idea, thank you, but I'm just thinking that if the CV falls in the hands of a recruiter for the university who is not a faculty member, then (s)he will screen through the CV for some key words, and will look for "Work Experience".

Comment: @ScienceMan surely this is easily resolved by having a section near the beginning listing the positions you have held (i.e. "Work Experience"—in my CV I call this "Appointments"), and then separate sections later on which detail your teaching (courses taught, etc.) and research experience (papers published, talks given, etc.) separately. These sections will be chronological. Note that you should not include your teaching methods in your CV: it is not the appropriate place to talk about this, at least in the areas of academia I am familiar with.

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh, this is more an answer than a comment.